# Prevent IDM to download the mp3 file

Tags: javascript, audio-player

I have a simple mp3 player on my website using javascript. the problem is when I clicked the play button, the IDM download bar just appeared.

I don't want that music file be able to downloaded by IDM.

How to do that?

Thanks for reply.

Comment: I think there's few guaranteed way to prevent end user from downloading a resource from your website while still make that resource accessible. "Opening" is somewhat downloading, after all.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on similar type of project. If you want to stop IDM you will have to change the file type or you can change the file extension while uploading the mp3 files.

And if you want to be more secure then you will have to play a song using a script instead of direct mp3 location.

Thanks
Onjon

Comment: Thanks Onjon, but What do you mean by "play a song using a script"?

Answer (score 0):

No. If you make a resource available on your site, it is downloadable. You may be able to make it somewhat more difficult for someone to download it, but there will always be a way for someone who is motivated enough and skilled enough to get the content you provide.

The only sure way of not allowing a resource to be downloadable is to not provide it at all.